# How to confirm if TimeSync service is enabled on a RHEL 8.2 VM running in Azure?

Tags: linux, azure, time

Im new to linux - so im abit confused if i have to do any best practice time sync config with Azure, or not?

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/accurate-time?redirectedfrom=MSDN#allowing-linux-to-use-hyper-v-host-time

The above link mentions: "For Linux guests running in Hyper-V, clients are typically configured to use the NTP daemon for time synchronization against NTP servers. If the Linux distribution supports the TimeSync version 4 protocol and the Linux guest has the TimeSync integration service enabled, then it will synchronize against the host time. This could lead to inconsistent time keeping if both methods are enabled."

How can i confirm this?
How can i confirm if TimeSync service is enabled on my RHEL 8.2 VM running in Azure?

Also how can i confirm if my ntp daemaon is configured for time synchronization against NTP servers?

As part of my investigation I have run the following on the RHEL 8.2 VM (running in Azure)
My findings on this lab are that ntp is not configured directly (/etc/ntp.conf does not exist and (as recorded in earlier comments) the ntpq command is not found,.

```
[user@vm-aep-dev-eastu ~]$ service ntpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status ntpd.service
Unit ntpd.service could not be found
```

.

however "chrony" is active.Chrony appears to be synchronising the system clock with NTP servers.

```
systemctl status chronyd
● chronyd.service - NTP client/server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/chronyd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-07-16 08:58:39 UTC; 7h ago
```

Other details:

```
$ /sbin/lsmod | egrep -i "^hv|hyperv"
hv_utils 36864 2
hv_balloon 28672 0
hyperv_fb 20480 1
hv_netvsc 86016 0
hv_storvsc 20480 4
hid_hyperv 16384 0
hyperv_keyboard 16384 0
hv_vmbus 114688 7 hv_balloon,hv_utils,hv_netvsc,hid_hyperv,hv_storvsc,hyperv_keyboard,hyperv_fb
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the reply helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

From the document [Time sync for Linux VMs in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/time-sync),

> On Ubuntu 19.10 and later versions, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and
> CentOS 8.x, chrony is configured to use a PTP source clock.

For more information about Red Hat and NTP, see [Configure NTP](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-configuring_ntp_using_ntpd#s1-Configure_NTP).

> If both chrony and VMICTimeSync sources are enabled simultaneously,
> you can mark one as prefer, which sets the other source as a backup.
> Because NTP services do not update the clock for large skews except
> after a long period, the VMICTimeSync will recover the clock from
> paused VM events far more quickly than NTP-based tools alone.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/time-sync#chrony) for more details.